# How to import Button1 from UserControl1 into Form1

Tags: vb.net

I tried this but it didn't work.

I also tried this `Button1.Click` from `Startpage(UserControl1)` input to `Form1`.

My code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Startpage.Button1.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no "importing". The only thing you can include in a `Handles` clause is an event of a field declared `WithEvents`. If you don't have such a field then you would have to use `AddHandler` to register the event handler. Note that you could declare your own field and assign that `Button` to it if you wanted to, but that would be rather dodgy.

Comment: That said, the proper way to do this would for the user control to handler the `Click` event of it's own `Button` and then raise an event of its own that the form could then handle.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this to be the least desirable option:

```
Private WithEvents StartpageButton1 As Button

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    StartpageButton1 = Startpage.Button1
End Sub

Private Sub StartpageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartpageButton1.Click
    '...
End Sub
```

I would consider this a better option:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Startpage.Button1, AddressOf StartpageButton1
End Sub

Private Sub StartpageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    RemoveHandler Startpage.Button1, AddressOf StartpageButton1
End Sub
```

I would consider this the best option:

```
Public Event Button1Click As EventHandler

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent Button1Click(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

That part would go in the user control and then this would go in the form:

```
Private Sub Startpage_Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Startpage.Button1Click
    '...
End Sub
```